# How to save auto-generated primary key value into second column right after inserting new row

Tags: postgresql, express

While inserting a new row in a table, I want to save auto-generated primary key value into second column of same row right after inserting new row.

Let's say:

I have a table name `teacher` with three columns `id, pid, name`.

`id` is the primary key and `pid` can be repetitive.

Now whenever I insert a new row, `id` will be incremented automatically.

I want to copy that auto-incremented value of the `id` column into the `pid` column in same row using postgresql query.

Can you guide me how I can achieve this using a postgresql query?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a `before insert` [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on table `teacher`. In order to implement it you need a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

```sql
create or replace function pid_bi_tf() returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  if NEW.pid is null then
    NEW.pid := NEW.id;
  end if;
  return NEW;
end;
$$;

create trigger pid_bi_t
 before insert on teacher
 for each row
 execute procedure pid_bi_tf();
```

I do not understand why you would need this but probably you have a good reason. You may consider this option: Unless there is an explicit value for field `pid` leave a `null` value in it. When querying it use this expression: `coalesce(pid, id)`.